# SASS SCSS: Return the actual RESULT in pixel of the calculation between vh and px

Tags: sass, height, calc

I wondering if is possibile for a SASS function to return the actual result of a calculation between differnt types of mesure such as vh and pixels.

```
@function scren_height() {
  $size: calc(100vh - 1px + 1px);
  @return $size;
}
```

The return of this function is calc(100vh - 1px + 1px); and not a pixel mesure or 100vh only.

Comment: `vh` is dependant of the viewport, sass being compiled, it has no idea of how much a vh is in pixel.

Comment: Thank you @Amaury Hanser, I will manage that in other ways!